# Why does connecting to a T-Mobile hotspot connection cause everything to go haywire?

Tags: wireless, internet

It works fine at first and then slowly degrades by disconnecting me, throwing every other available wifi connection off the map and then freezing the whole computer when I turn off the wifi toggle.

I have a broadcom wifi card. 23.04 desktop (planning on updating to 23.10 tomorrow) and I use a tmobile home internet thing that has a sim card in it, it has ethernet ports and it works fine on ethernet and other wifi connections but when I try to connect through our tmobile wifi it just kicks me off.

Comment: i wonder if it could be my drivers